# "bash: expo: command not found" after installing expo-cli in Mac

Tags: reactjs, native

- expo-cli@3.27.4
  updated 1 package in 51.434s
  Sachin's-MacBook-Pro:~ sachin$ expo --version
  bash: expo: command not found
  Sachin's-MacBook-Pro:~ sachin$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved my problem

Go to your root account by typing

1. sudo su
2. npm install expo-cli --global
3. expo init myNewProject.

I hope it helps some one.